# How to parameterize table name using jdbi query annotations?

Tags: java, prepared-statement

The below gives an error. And all my searching indicates that the table name needs to be hardcoded. But possibly there is some clever workaround I couldn't find?

```
public interface MyDao {

  @SqlQuery("INSERT INTO :tbl (ID) VALUES (:id)")
  void logInserts1817(@Bind("tbl") String tbl, @Bind("id") String id);
}
```

Comment: So, you don't know the table name beforehand, but you know it has an `ID` column?

Comment: No. I will be inserting into a bunch of tables, say 20. So I'd rather my DAO not have 20 different methods, each hardcoded with a different table name.